# JSTL EL tags not working in tomcat 8

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, tomcat8

I am migrating my application from tomcat 6 to tomcat 8.

For tomcat 6, I've used `jdt-compiler.jar` for compiling jsps and `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` for accessing jstl tags.

Since this has caused issues in jsp compilation in tomcat 8, removed those jars and added jstl-1.2.jars. Now jsp compiled successfully in runtime compilation.

But another issue popped up after I have precompiled jsps using jspc ant task. Expressions in EL tags are not evaluated in the jsps when I run the application.

My web-app definition:

> < web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
>                         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"   version="3.1">

and jstl uri in jsp:

> < %@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

I wonder why application runs fine in runtime compilation but not when using precompiled jsps compiled using ant compilation?

Can anyone help me out? Struggling with this issue for hours.

Comment: Did you find this problem? I have the same situation.